# Cannot convert byte array to char array and vice versa while sending through serial port

Tags: java, binary, serial-port, arrays

I have to do following things

1. append 2 bytes in hex at the end of the char array containing 4 bytes , so the resultant is 6 byte.
2. Convert the above 6 byte byte array to char array to pass it to function crcresult. (the function only accept char array).
3. Finally merge the crc 2 byte at the end of the 6 byte.

I have tested the following program in separate java class and it worked.

```
  public class CharBytetest
  {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
      char charbuffer1[] = {0x01,0x05,0x00,0x03};
      byte[] bufferbyte1 = new String(charbuffer1).getBytes();// converts chararray  to byte array

      byte byte4 = (byte)0xFF;
      byte byte5 = (byte)0x00;

      byte[] bufferbytemerge1 = new byte[bufferbyte1.length+2];
      System.arraycopy(bufferbyte1, 0, bufferbytemerge1, 0, bufferbyte1.length);
      bufferbytemerge1[bufferbyte1.length]= byte4;
      bufferbytemerge1[bufferbyte1.length +1 ]= byte5;

      //bufferbytemerge1 contains 6 byte (charbuffer1 + byte4 + byte5 )
      String str = new String(bufferbytemerge1);

      //bufferbytemerge1  converted to char array
      char[] charbuffer2 = str.toCharArray();
      byte[] bufferbyte2 = new String(charbuffer2).getBytes();

      int crcresult;
      //char array sent to crc function
      crcresult = CalculateCRC.CRC16(charbuffer2,6);

      byte byte1 = (byte)((crcresult >> 8) & 0xFF); // first 8 bits of last 16 bits
      byte byte0 = (byte)(crcresult & 0xFF);        // last 8 bits

      byte[] bufferbytemerge2 = new byte[bufferbyte2.length + 2];
      System.arraycopy(bufferbyte2, 0, bufferbytemerge2, 0, bufferbyte2.length);// copy original data stored in bytebuffer
      bufferbytemerge2[bufferbyte2.length] = byte1;                      // append crc16 byte 1  
      bufferbytemerge2[bufferbyte2.length + 1] = byte0;                      // append crc16 byte 2  

      //bufferbytemerge2 contains total 8 bytes
      for (byte b : bufferbytemerge2){
        System.out.format("0X%x ", b);
      }
    }
  }
```

The output seen is

```
0X1 0X5 0X0 0X3 0Xff 0X0 0X7c 0X3a
```

But my problem when i implemented the above thing to send "bufferbytemerge2" in the serial port specifically modbus, conversion error is seen as

```
java.lang.ArraIndexOutOfBoundsException : 65454
at com.wexsnet.wesModbus.comm.req.CalculateCRC.crc16 <CalculateCRC.java:59>
```

I tried to analyse byte obtained at each step and it seemed that problem is at step2. ie when bufferbytemerge1 is converted to char array.

As per the above code , "bufferbyte2" should contain 01 05 00 03 FF 00 but when i try to send "bufferbyte2"  it is sending 01 05 00 03 ef bf bf 00

So is it because conversion of "bufferbytemerge1" byte array to char array "charbuffer2" is not correct . or conversion of "charbuffer2" char array to byte array "bufferbyte2" is not correct. Please help how can we convert it correctly.

Comment: When you call `new String(byte[])` you're invoking unspecified behavior with non-valid encoding. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte[]%29

Answer (score 7):

Do not use `char` to hold a byte value in Java.  I realize that is standard practice in C, but in Java bytes belong in `byte` arrays only.

Every time you convert bytes to a String or convert a String to bytes, you are using the encoder or decoder of a `Charset`.  In many Charsets (including UTF-8, which is what your system apparently uses), not every byte value can be converted to a character;  such bytes will be discarded or replaced with some default number.  And in many Charsets, some characters do not correspond to a single byte, but rather to multiple bytes, which is where your `ef bf bf` is coming from.

That is why your use of `new String(byte[])` and `String.getByes()` is corrupting your data.

Do not use `char` arrays.  Do not convert bytes to or from Strings.  Use only `byte` arrays to hold bytes.

If you want to convert a `byte` array to an array of 16-bit values, use [`ByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) to convert it to a `short` array:

```
short[] sixteenBitValues = new short[byteArray.length / 2];
ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray).asShortBuffer().get(sixteenBitValues);
```

In general, if you want to append bytes to a byte array, you should use a `ByteBuffer`:

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(oldByteArray.length + 2);
buffer.put(oldByteArray);
buffer.asShortBuffer().put(crcresult);
byte[] newByteArray = buffer.array();
```

If your CRC16 method will only operate on a `char` array, you need to avoid using String, or any other method that will invoke a Charset encoding, and force the bytes to `char` values yourself:

```
char[] charBuffer2 = new char[byteBuffer.length];
for (int i = 0; i < byteBuffer.length; i++) {
    charBuffer2[i] = (char) (byteBuffer[i] & 0xff);
}
```

It sounds like your CRC16 method is making the C-based assumption that `char` holds a single byte, so if you have any control over that class, you should change it to accept a `byte[]` argument.

Comment: thank you for the reponse . but i need to convert byte array to char array because the function crcresult accepts char array . so how to convert it effectively.

Comment: Also when i use , byte buffer , error is seen as  " the import java/nio/ByteBuffer is not valid.

Comment: Updated my answer.  As for the import error, your import line should look like this: `import java.nio.ByteBuffer;`

Comment: I am getting the following error: "Semantic Error: The import "java/nio/ByteBuffer" is not valid, since it does not name a type in a package." . how to proceed ahead. please suggest. i am using eclipse

Comment: I don't know how that class can be missing.  What OS are you using?  Did you install Java separately from Eclipse?  If so, how did you install it?

Comment: "Do not use char to hold a byte value in Java." – but what about when an API gives you a byte array whose contents are valid characters (in some known character encoding)? It's rare, but sometimes you don't have a choice.

Comment: If you have control over that API, fix it.  If you don't have control over that API, you should immediately convert the returned byte array to a String or CharBuffer using the API's charset.  Personally I would add a comment stating that the API is guaranteed (or at least known) to return bytes corresponding to characters encoded in that charset.